# Handling huge ajax response with javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, performance, browser

I'm building a site that uses [jQuery File Tree](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/03/jquery-file-tree/#demo). Sometimes the AJAX response from the server is huge: 900 KB, 70000 'files' (I'm not really displaying files).

Of course displaying this puts a lot of strain on javascript (client side) and it happens that the browser freezes because of that.

What would be possible solutions for this? Can you "tell the browser" to expect a big load (as you do with max_execution_time and memory_limit in PHP).
The other idea was to break down the request to several smaller. There would be quite some coding needed to do this and I'm wondering: would this even work? Can browsers handle manipulating such a big number of DOM nodes?

Any other ideas about how to deal with this?

Comment: Perhaps you can develop it so that only the roots of the tree download to start with, and then when a branch is opened that branch's content is downloaded. Either that, or some other way of partitioning up your data.

Comment: _Can you "tell the browser" to expect a big load?_ No.

Comment: You can get partial responses with ajax and then stop generating html if data becomes too big

Answer (score 3):

I think a better way to approach this solution is an "on-demand", or "lazy-load" solution. Only display the roots of the file tree, then grab data via AJAX when the user tries to expand any of the nodes to see its children.

This way you don't load all the data at once, but do it piecemeal instead.

Comment: that's what I'm doing, that's what the jQuery File tree plugin is build for. However some of the children are really really big

Comment: I guess you would have to implement some sort of paging solution, then. Split the children into multiple pieces and then request for them piece by piece.